# Error after upgrading from Spring 3.2.3 to Spring 4

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-4

After I upgrade my web app from Spring 3.2.3 to Spring 4 I am experiencing `NoSuchMethodError`:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.setDefaultRolePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

This is from my current pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I've followed [this](https://samerabdelkafi.wordpress.com/2014/05/29/spring-data-jpa/) tutorial. The google search returned only one result, [this](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2893) one.

Is there a way to explicitly see what version of spring-security works with spring-core version, or vice versa ? I think this is the problem, the version of one api isn't compatible with the version of another or some exception are thrown, like this one. I though the Maven should know that.

EDIT:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.setDefaultRolePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;)V
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:28)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:17)
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.createEvaluationContext(AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java:47)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:32)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18)
at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62)
at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:106)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at com.fpx.edm.services.authentication.JwtAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JwtAuthenticationFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:220)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:184)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:301)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricFilterAutoConfiguration$MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricFilterAutoConfiguration.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1736)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1695)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The one from the title.

Comment: To be clear you updated Spring Framework from 3.2.3 to 4.0?

Comment: Yes, I've upgraded from 3.2.3 to 4.1.0 first, but some exceptions were thrown. After that I set it to 4.0.0, the tomcat deployed my project but in the browser that exception appeared

Comment: It's the same as in the link I've posted. I haven't saw no root exceptions for this one.

Comment: @PavelHoral can you explain why you down vote the question? I've answered your question and no other exceptions were to be posted.

Comment: Please learn to **always include full stack trace when asking for help**. It does not matter that you don't see anything suspicious there. Others might.

Comment: Please update the post to include the full stacktrace

Comment: A general tip on compatibility is to look at the platform BOM (io.spring.platform:platform-bom), which should give you pretty much all the tested compatible versions that you might need.

Comment: It looks as though spring-security-web is on your classpath twice (once with spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE and once with a prior version of spring-security-web). Can you look inside your war's lib folder and list all of your spring-security-* jars?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've solve it. The problem was that my spring security was at a lower version that required for spring 4. The simple update of spring security to 4.0.0 as well fixed my problem.

As many of you may already saw the exception isn't very clearly about the problem. I don't know why this was happening nor what other, maybe a better, solution exists but this solved my issue.

I will accept this answer and maybe it help someone.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The versions in this answer is the same as the OP, what is changed? Did you change anything to 4.0.0?

Comment: Both spring-security-core and spring-security-web versions were changed to 4.0.0.

Comment: This error shows up even if you do not include spring-security-core in pom.xml. So include security core as well.

Comment: thanks @user1117972 ! adding the spring-security-core obviously matters.