# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy'

Tags: maven, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am getting the below error for my application when implementing spring security.  I searched the net and it may be due to different versions of dependecies.  But the versions in my pom look fine to me. Any idea?

```
 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChainProxy': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.setDefaultRolePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:636) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) ~[spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479) ~[spring-context-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306) ~[spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112) [spring-web-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4887) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5381) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549) [catalina.jar:7.0.39]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_17]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_17]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebSecurityExpressionRoot.setDefaultRolePrefix(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:31) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.createSecurityExpressionRoot(DefaultWebSecurityExpressionHandler.java:17) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.expression.AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.createEvaluationContext(AbstractSecurityExpressionHandler.java:47) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:33) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter.vote(WebExpressionVoter.java:18) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:62) ~[spring-security-core-3.2.7.RELEASE.jar:3.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.checkLoginPageIsntProtected(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:191) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.http.DefaultFilterChainValidator.validate(DefaultFilterChainValidator.java:36) ~[spring-security-config-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.afterPropertiesSet(FilterChainProxy.java:167) ~[spring-security-web-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511) ~[spring-beans-3.2.13.RELEASE.jar:3.2.13.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.temptingplaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>temptingplaces</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>org.temptingplaces.web</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <name>temptingplaces-web Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.temptingplaces.services</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.temptingplaces.common</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>temptingplaces-web</finalName>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another reason is because of missing spring-security-core dependency 
Try to include spring-security-core in your project , if you are using maven pom.xml add

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId> 
    <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

I've the same problem. 
The  Spring's sercurity dependencies should not be in a lower version than the Spring itself (you can see the same answer [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399154/error-after-upgrading-from-spring-3-2-3-to-spring-4)

The security dependencies you're using is 4.0.2, while the Spring is 4.2.0. Try to use both in the same version.

Hope it help.